# sql statement to retrieve the last entry value from database

Tags: sql, sql-server

My auto number has 2 parts

3 digits are serial number and last 8 digits are month and year of Invoice

For example: `001072013`

So if I want a next `InvoiceNo`

I select from last entry of invoice number from database like this

```
select TOP 1 InvoiceNo 
from BuyInvoice
```

cut the first 3 digits, and make increment, and combine it to month and year of Invoice

So it would be `002072013`

The problem is the above statement doesn't return the last entry value

and ascending and descending both don't work

Comment: To save yourself a lot of trouble, implement an invoicedate column in your table.

Comment: Is this a legacy database you're required to work with or a database over which you have design control? Your approach here is very old-fashioned legacy approach, far from today's best practices.

Comment: Just a side note: it seems to me like you will run out of serial numbers pretty fast given that three digits only can represent 0-999. I would seriously consider having the serial as a separate column allowing for higher growth and constructing the InvoiceNo using a stored procedure or view.

Comment: thank you all for your comment 
never mind about running out of serial number because i have thought about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try:

```
select TOP 1 InvoiceNo 
from BuyInvoice order by right(InvoiceNo,4) desc,
  right(InvoiceNo, 6) desc, 
  InvoiceNo desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select TOP 1 InvoiceNo 
  from BuyInvoice order by InvoiceNo desc
```

Comment: If you have the following invoices: `001071913`, `002071913`, `001072013` then this solution returns `002071913` which is wrong bencause the last invoice is from 07/20/13 (mm/dd/yy).

Answer (score 0):

*I assume that `BuyInvoice` table has an `InvoiceDate` column that has the same values like the `date` part of `InvoiceNo` column.* In this case I would use (the solution is not tested):

```
DECLARE @InvoiceDate DATE;
SET @InvoiceDate='2013-07-20';

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DECLARE @LastInvoiceNo VARCHAR(9);

SELECT TOP(1) @LastInvoiceNo=bi.InvoiceNo 
-- This table hint (UPDLOCK) take a U lock on this row[s] so any concurrent [similar] transactions will have to wait till this transaction is finished
-- This will prevent duplicated new InvoiceNo 
FROM dbo.BuyInvoice bi WITH(UPDLOCK) 
WHERE bi.InvoiceDate=@InvoiceDate
ORDER BY bi.InvoiceNo DESC;

DECLARE @Seq SMALLINT;
SET @Seq=ISNULL(CONVERT(SMALLINT,LEFT(@LastInvoiceNo,3)),0);
SET @Seq=@Seq+1;

DECLARE @NewInvoiceNo VARCHAR(9);
SET @NewInvoiceNo=RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),@Seq),3)+STUFF(STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@InvoiceDate,101),3,1,''),5,1,''); -- Convert style 101 = mm/dd/yyyy

...

INSERT dbo.BuyInvoice(InvoiceNo,InvoiceDate,...)
VALUES (@NewInvoiceNo,@InvoiceDate,...);
...

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Also, I would use `BEGIN TRY ... END CATCH` to intercept exceptions and to rollback this transaction if needed ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) : example B).

Also, I will create following indices:

```
-- This way, the InvoiceNo column will have uniques values
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IUN_BuyInvoice_InvoiceNo
ON dbo.BuyInvoice(InvoiceNo);
GO
-- This index is used by SELECT TOP(1) ... query
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IN_BuyInvoice_InvoiceDate_InvoiceNo
ON dbo.BuyInvoice(InvoiceDate,InvoiceNo);
GO
```

Comment: Note: if you don't have `InvoiceDate` column then you could add a computed column thus: `ALTER TABLE dbo.BuyInvoice ADD InvoiceDate AS (CONVERT(DATE,STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(InvoiceNo,6),3,0,'/'),6,0,'/20'),101)) ;`; This computed column is not persisted so will not consume additional storage space in heap/clustered index except (of course) `IUN_BuyInvoice_InvoiceDate_InvoiceNo` index.

Comment: Note: After `SET @Seq=@Seq+1;` I would add this check `IF @Seq>999 <br> BEGIN <br> RAISERROR('@Seq exhausted',16,1); <br> END;`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select top 1 InvoiceNo from BuyInvoice order by left(InvoiceNo,3) desc
```