# Generate autoincrementing varchar primary key in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to generate varchar auto incremented primary key (order id) values for each individual order placed as shown in below format.

**'O201307270001'**

**'O'** for Order,  **'20130727'** for date (27-jul-2013),  **'0001'** for auto incremented value

i want to **restart the auto incremented numbers** (last 4 numbers in above id) start from **'1'** when new day starts.

Below is the examples of how I want the order ids to be generated for order placed at different time and day:

```
O201307270001   when date is like '2013-07-27 01:23:45.235'
O201307270002   when date is like '2013-07-27 03:12:22.212'
.
.
.
O201307270040   when date is like '2013-07-27 11:34:56.189'
.
.
//Now when new day starts:
O201307280001   when date is like '2013-07-28 00:00:00.000'
O201307280002   when date is like '2013-07-28 00:13:05.000'
```

please help me, how i can do it

Comment: Look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745713/sql-statement-to-retrieve-the-last-entry-value-from-database/17746628#17746628).

Comment: Did any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I suggest, which has the (pretty big :) ) advantage of not reading the target table and will give better performance as your table grows.

You'll have to create a short stored procedure and a parameter table.

Just call the stored procedure and it will return the right Id :

```
DECLARE @NewOrderId AS CHAR(13)

EXEC usp_NewOrderId @NewOrderId OUTPUT

SELECT @NewOrderId
```

This is what you need to create :

```
CREATE TABLE OrderNumberGenerator (
  Id INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1),
  CreatedDate DATE DEFAULT(GETDATE()) 
 )
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_NewOrderId 
(@NewOrderIdOut char(13) OUTPUT ) 
AS 
BEGIN

   IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM OrderNumberGenerator WHERE CreatedDate <> CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) )
    TRUNCATE TABLE OrderNumberGenerator --restart the counter everyday :)

  INSERT INTO OrderNumberGenerator DEFAULT VALUES

  SELECT @NewOrderIdOut = 
  'O' +
  CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) +
  RIGHT( '000' + CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS VARCHAR(4)) ,  4 ) 

END
```

**Check it out here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fdb91/4**

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recomend you not to use this varchar generated code as the primary key of your table, use a numerical value instead and save this generated string as an order code on a separate column (It will keep you away from nightmares with future querys). You can flag this code column as "unique" and get the same result.

About how to generate the order code, if the logic behind is not as basic as an autoincrement or something like that, it would be better to have this donde on an upper layer of your system (if there is one).

Comment: Varchar can be use as primary keys, this orderNumber wouldn't be a bad choice for a PK. Keys are business related, when it comes to indexes and performance issue, it's not really the same problem. Even if I believe this column could be use as a clustered index too, since it is sequentially generated

Comment: "Varchar can be use as primary keys", of course, I dindn't say they can't.

"Keys are business related", well, I have to disagree here, I guess that in most cases we use keys as identifiers of our business entities, but they are not the same, like in this users table:

UserId -- Key, related or not to the business logic

Email  -- Identifier, related to the BL

FirstName

Comment: Just sayin, keys are logical relations, whereas indexes are about storage and performance. You're mixing those two concepts in your answer

Comment: Never mentioned indexes on my answers, you did. Maybe "nightmares with future querys" lead you to think about indexes, but I was refering to having to match that order code in the related tables, the lock to save the autoincremental value "0001" (it seems that no more than 9999 can be placed in one day), or having to use a "select * from Orders where WeirdOrderId in (...)", this query type ends up ordering the results by "WeirdOrderId". You can create and maintain all the indexes you want on this column, but that will be always more expensive that handling a simple and well known numerical id.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger, or as I would recommend, a `CreateOrder` stored procedure.

Here are the steps you'd have to follow:

1. Compute the current date prefix. `'O' + CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 112)`
2. Select the last order number from the table. `SELECT MAX(OrderNum) FROM Order`
3. If the last order number has the current date prefix, extract the numeric suffix, increment it, and append it to the date prefix. `WHEN @CurrentPrefix = LEFT(@LastOrder, 9) THEN @CurrentPrefix + RIGHT('000' + (CONVERT(int, RIGHT(@LastOrder, 4)) + 1))`
4. Otherwise, just use `0001` as the suffix. `ELSE @CurrentPrefix + '0001'`
5. Use the generated key to perform the insert.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @autoInc VARCHAR(25)
SET @autoInc='O'+(SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 112))+
               CAST(((SELECT COUNT(*) 
                     FROM table 
                 WHERE autoColumn like 'O'+(SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(),112))+'%') 
                       +1 ) AS VARCHAR(5))
```

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*)` doesn't work if an order gets deleted from earlier in the day.

Comment: ya . such a problem there. thank you Gabe. i didn't noticed that

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers already pointed out doing this might be a bad idea, but if you want to anyway this code should accomplish what you want I believe. I haven't tried all corner cases but for the small test data provided it was working.

Some test data that i tried:

```
declare @tab table (pk char(13))
insert @tab values ('O201307270001')
insert @tab values ('O201307270002')
insert @tab values ('O201307270003')
insert @tab values ('O201307278999')
insert @tab values ('O201307280001')
insert @tab values ('O201307280002')
insert @tab values ('O201307290001')
```

And then the actual code:

```
SELECT 
  CASE ISNULL(MAX(RIGHT(pk,4)),0) 
    WHEN 0 THEN 'O' + CONVERT(CHAR(8),GETDATE(),112) + '0001' 
   ELSE 'O' + CONVERT(CHAR(8),GETDATE(),112) + RIGHT(CAST(MAX(RIGHT(pk,4)) + 10001 AS CHAR(5)),4) END 
FROM @tab 
WHERE SUBSTRING(pk,2,8) = CONVERT(CHAR(8),GETDATE(),112)
```

Ideally it should be wrapped up in a function, and probably use locking too to avoid the same key being handed out twice.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE OrderNumberGenerator (
  [ID] INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1),
 [New_ID]  AS 'O'+CONVERT(varchar)
 )
GO