# How to define a primary key as a specific format. Ie acc1234567 and then increment.

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Im using EntityFramework-Core and I'm trying to figure out how to have my primary key be in a specific format. Something like acc0001 and then increment with each new entry ie. acc0002, acc0003 etc

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Auto incrementing a string doesn't really make sense. What's wrong with just storing an account id as a int, primary key ,auto increment, and then when you want to print it's "name", you just prepend "acc"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate autoincrementing varchar primary key in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17899342/generate-autoincrementing-varchar-primary-key-in-sql-server)

Comment: Also please remember that having a varchar as primary key might really suck for quering... (eg `SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE AccId > 1000`

Comment: I thought to prepend it. Its common to see this and so I thought there would be a better way to do it.